# can´t rename column of dataframe which is created from numpy array

Tags: python, pandas, numpy, spyder

I created a pd.dataframe from an numpy array, the header of the single column of the array is '0', I want to rename this column, doesn´t matter for me if it is renamed in the array or only after having converted it into a dataframe.

```
theor_power_output         =np.interp(wind_speed, power_curve_wind_speeds, power_curve_values, left=0, right=0)
tpo                        =pd.DataFrame(theor_power_output)
tpo.rename(columns={'0':'TheorPwr'}, inplace=True)
```

as the df.rename is working on another dataframe in the same code, I guess it has something to do with the header of the numpy-array. Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: what is the error you are getting? and it may be `0` instead of `'0'`

Comment: A `numpy` array does not have a header.  With a simple 2d array argument, `pandas` just assigns the numerical index, `[0,1,2...]`.  Use the `columns` parameter.

Comment: Thank you for your help. I circumvent the problem by using the ```assign``` method. in this case I can assign the array to a dataframe with the column name that I want.

Comment: try `tpo.rename(columns={0:'TheoPwr'}, inplace=True)`.

Answer (score 0):

In cases like this, you should have started from printing column names
in the DataFrame in question:

```
print(tpo.columns)
```

or, if you use e.g. *Jupyter Notebook*, just `tpo.columns`.

Then you would have had surely noticed that column names are just
consecutive **numbers** (not char strings).